# Find all next classes until class jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="type_1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type_1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type_2">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type_2">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type_1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, if I click `.type_1` all `.type_2`, until the next `.type_1`, should toggle.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$(".type_1").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".type_2").toggle();
});
```

**EDIT**: I also tried with `.nextAll()` but this will toggle ALL `.type_2` Only those after the clicked `.type_1` should toggle.

But this only allows me to toggle the first encountered `.type_2`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `next()` only returns one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can try a nextUntil

https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

```
$(".type_1").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".type_2").toggle();
});
```

Comment: I've read it, but this will toggle all `.type_2`.. I need only to toggle a "group" of `.type_2`.